# How to index arguments of a command in a loop?

Tags: macros, loops, arguments

Here is my problem: I try to write a command with some arguments (let's say 4) and I need to loop on the arguments. Like this:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{multicol}
\renewcommand{\LayoutChoiceField}[2]{%
\leavevmode #2 #1%
}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newcounter{itemp}

\newcommand\qqc[4]{%
    \setcounter{itemp}{1}
    \textbf{Question :}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \loop
            {%
            \item[{\ChoiceMenu[name=Q,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{=1}}]
                                                         {#{\the\value{itemp}}}\\ 
            }    
        \stepcounter{itemp}
        \ifnum \value{itemp} < 5 
        \repeat

    \end{enumerate}  
    \end{multicols}    
    }%
\begin{document}
\qqc{I'm not Bill Gates, but you already know that}{I'm not John Gates}{Nor Joshua Gates}{Neither Kevin Gates. I don't rap.}
\end{document}
```

Obviously, the problem is in {#{\the\value{itemp}}}. I would like to get #1, then #2, #3 and #4, but not simply the string; something I can deal with (for example to print the temp-th argument)
Moreover, I don't think it is approriate to use etoolbox since we can get comma and many different symbols in the arguments, hence, no proper delimiter for a list...
If you have any idea, you are more than welcome.
All my best,
Thierry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome! Rather than iterating over the arguments I would pass a list to the command and iterate over the list. If you keep loading `tikz`, you could use `\foreach` for that, but you do not necessarily need that, you could use also `\@for` here.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{multicol}
\renewcommand{\LayoutChoiceField}[2]{%
\leavevmode #2 #1%
}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\qqc[1]{%
    \textbf{Question :}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \@for\temp:=#1\do{%
            \item 
            [{\ChoiceMenu[name=Q,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{=1}}]{\temp}
            }    
    \end{enumerate}  
    \end{multicols}    
    }%
\makeatother    
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\qqc{{I'm not Bill Gates, but you already know that},%
{I'm not John Gates},%
{Nor Joshua Gates},%
{Neither Kevin Gates. I don't rap.}}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I had to wrap the code into `\begin{Form}` and `\end{Form}` and of course do not know what you have in mind.

**EDIT**: Removed the unnecessary counter, as pointed out by Ulrich Diez (Thanks!). This was an oversight, the content of the answer did not change.

Comment: Always the same sad story. Sigh.

Comment: It is weird isn't it? You posted first with an elegant answer and then another less elegant post attracts more votes. I don't understand it either.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I am nevertheless grateful. It was a stupid oversight, which is in the worst case confusing. And no, please be assured that this was never about you. As I said, I am still shocked by the events that left to the departure of jfbu, and I do not think that concerns you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: I was talking about the solution you provide... Not your comments!

Answer (score 4):

Just use a macro to do the repetitive task. I also fixed the start of `multicols`, so you don't risk a page break between “Question:” and the questions.

```latex
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{hyperref} % should be last


\renewcommand{\LayoutChoiceField}[2]{\leavevmode #2 #1}

\newcommand{\doitem}[1]{%
  \item[{\ChoiceMenu[name=Q,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{=1}}]{#1}
}

\newcommand\qqc[4]{%
  \textbf{Question:}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \doitem{#1}\doitem{#2}\doitem{#3}\doitem{#4}
  \end{enumerate}  
  \end{multicols}    
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\qqc{I'm not Bill Gates, but you already know that}
    {I'm not John Gates}
    {Nor Joshua Gates}
    {Neither Kevin Gates. I don't rap.}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a change of syntax you can accommodate how many items you wish. The syntax is the same as suggested by [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/541787/4427).

```latex
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{hyperref} % should be last


\renewcommand{\LayoutChoiceField}[2]{\leavevmode #2 #1}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \duncanidaho_qqc_item:n
 {
  \item[{\ChoiceMenu[name=Q,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{=1}}]{#1}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\qqc}{m}
 {
  \begin{multicols}{2}[\textbf{Question:}]
  \begin{enumerate}
  \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \duncanidaho_qqc_item:n
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\qqc{
  {I'm not Bill Gates, but you already know that}
  {I'm not John Gates}
  {Nor Joshua Gates}
  {Neither Kevin Gates. I don't rap.}
}
\end{Form}

\begin{Form}
\qqc{
  {I'm not Bill Gates, but you already know that}
  {I'm not John Gates}
  {Nor Joshua Gates}
  {Neither Kevin Gates. I don't rap.}
  {Whatever}
  {Something else}
  {Stop here}
  {One more thing}
}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

*You program in LaTeX. LaTeX is based on TeX as described in the TeXbook of Donald Ervin Knuth. Basically LaTeX is just a set of macros written in TeX and packaged as a so-called format in order to have these macros loaded automatically when loading the TeX-program via an executable that is called latex/latex.exe/whatsoever.
Low-level-concepts introduced in the TeXbook also apply to LaTeX.
Thus in the following explanations things where I use the phrase "TeX" also apply when programming in LaTeX.*

Think of TeX-macros as tokens that during expansion get removed from the token-stream and which additionally trigger the removal of more tokens from the token-stream followed by insertion of tokens into the token-stream.

"Removal of more tokens from the token-stream" is done according to the rules provided by the *⟨parameter text⟩* which belongs to the macro's *⟨definition⟩*.

"Insertion of tokens into the token-stream" is done according to the rules provided by the *⟨balanced text⟩* which also belongs to the macro's *⟨definition⟩*.

The tokens inserted into the token-stream form the "replacement text".

**Syntax `#1`, `#2`, ..., `#9`** for denoting arguments of a macro **is available only at the time of defining the macro/at the time of providing the *⟨definition⟩* of the macro.** It is not available at the time of expanding the macro and afterwards processing the tokens which form the replacement text which comes from expanding the macro.

But a thing like `#{\the\value{itemp}}` is an attempt to make such syntax available at the time of expanding a macro and afterwards processing the replacement text of that macro. This is not possible in TeX.

As in TeX you cannot have processed more than nine arguments directly via a macro, i.e., without tricks like tail-recursively applying the same macro to several sets of arguments, looping over the numbers of arguments seems not needed to me. You can just do:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{multicol}
\renewcommand{\LayoutChoiceField}[2]{%
\leavevmode #2 #1%
}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newcommand\qqc[4]{%
    \textbf{Question :}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}
            \item 
            [{\ChoiceMenu[name=Q,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{=1}}]{#1}%
            \item 
            [{\ChoiceMenu[name=Q,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{=1}}]{#2}%
            \item 
            [{\ChoiceMenu[name=Q,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{=1}}]{#3}%
            \item 
            [{\ChoiceMenu[name=Q,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{=1}}]{#4}%
    \end{enumerate}  
    \end{multicols}    
    }%
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\qqc{I'm not Bill Gates, but you already know that}{I'm not John Gates}{Nor Joshua Gates}{Neither Kevin Gates. I don't rap.}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

If you insist in having a loop where arguments can be addressed by an ordinal number denoting their position within a line-up of an arbitrary amount of arguments, I can offer a macro `\ExtractKthArg{⟨integer K⟩}{⟨list of undelimited args⟩}`:

```
\makeatletter
%% Code for \ExtractKthArg
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, 
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Extract K-th inner undelimited argument:
%%
%% \ExtractKthArg{<integer K>}{<list of undelimited args>} 
%% 
%% In case there is no K-th argument in <list of undelimited args> : 
%%   Does not deliver any token.
%% In case there is a K-th argument in <list of undelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver that K-th argument with one level of braces removed.
%%
%% Examples:
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{0}{ABCDE} yields: <nothing>
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{ABCDE} yields:  C
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{AB{CD}E} yields:  CD
%%   \ExtractKthArg{4}{{001}{002}{003}{004}{005}} yields: 004
%%   \ExtractKthArg{6}{{001}{002}{003}} yields: <nothing> 
%% 
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\ExtractKthArg[1]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  % #1: <integer number K>
  \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck[2]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{ }{%
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#2{}.}{ }{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{%
      \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#2\UD@SelDOm}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}%
      {\expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm{}%
\long\def\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1#2\UD@SelDOm{{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@firstoftwo{\expandafter}{} \UD@secondoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1}}%
}%
%% End of code for \ExtractKthArg.
\makeatother
%%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{multicol}
\renewcommand{\LayoutChoiceField}[2]{%
\leavevmode #2 #1%
}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newcounter{itemp}

\newcommand\qqc[4]{%
    \setcounter{itemp}{1}%
    \textbf{Question :}
    \begin{multicols}{2}%
    \begin{enumerate}
        \loop
            \item 
            [{\ChoiceMenu[name=Q,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{=1}}]{\ExtractKthArg{\value{itemp}}{{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}}%
        \stepcounter{itemp}%
        \ifnum \value{itemp} < 5 
        \repeat
    \end{enumerate}  
    \end{multicols}    
    }%
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\qqc{I'm not Bill Gates, but you already know that}{I'm not John Gates}{Nor Joshua Gates}{Neither Kevin Gates. I don't rap.}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

If you just wish to process all arguments one by one, but don't need the possibility of addressing/selecting/picking specific arguments, you can do tail-recursion:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{multicol}
\renewcommand{\LayoutChoiceField}[2]{%
\leavevmode #2 #1%
}

\newcommand\RecursionStopper{\RecursionStopper}%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\tailrecursive[2]{%
  % !!! #2 must not contain unbalanced \if../\else/\fi !!!
  \ifx\RecursionStopper#2%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
   {#1{#2}\tailrecursive{#1}}%
}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumerate}
\newcommand\qqc[4]{%
    \textbf{Question :}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \tailrecursive{%
         \item 
         [{\ChoiceMenu[name=Q,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{=1}}]%
      }{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{\RecursionStopper}%
    \end{enumerate}  
    \end{multicols}    
    }%
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\qqc{I'm not Bill Gates, but you already know that}{I'm not John Gates}{Nor Joshua Gates}{Neither Kevin Gates. I don't rap.}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[In my answer to the question "defining a new command with variable name in a loop"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539821/118714) I describe variants of a macro `\DoWithEachElementOfArgumentList`. This might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks very much. A bit complicated for me to understand but it does the job.