# How to turn string into command?

Tags: macros

I have commands called `\cta`, `\ctb`, `ctc`, `\ctd`.

I'd like to call these commands from within a loop, as follows:

```
\foreach \i in {a,b,c,d}{
% this is where I want to call the command 
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Like `\cta, \ctb, \ctc, \ctd.` (with punctuation) or just `\cta\ctb\ctc\ctd`?

Comment: @egreg just `\cta` without punctuation. There are four commands in total (although of course the number doesn't matter as I could loop as many as I wanted).

Comment: See also [How to use a string argument to create a macro name and invoke the resulting macro name? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598479/how-to-use-a-string-argument-to-create-a-macro-name-and-invoke-the-resulting-mac?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TeX primitives `\csname...\endcsname` allow to construct macro names.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\cta}{A}
\newcommand*{\ctb}{BB}
\newcommand*{\ctc}{CCC}
\newcommand*{\ctd}{DDDD}

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {a,b,c,d}{The content of \texttt{\expandafter\string\csname ct\i\endcsname} is \csname ct\i\endcsname.\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When TeX encounters

```
\csname ct\i\endcsname
```

it expands `\i` (and it keeps expanding) until only character tokens are obtained, and builds a control sequence with the corresponding "string". (An error is thrown if the expansion produces a non-character token.)

Comment: @campa The TeXbook is not always saying the whole truth…

Comment: @egreg That I have learnt... Thx.

Comment: Correction of my previous comment - as long as `\endlinechar` is taken into consideration, the expandable `\input`-primitive can be used inside `\csname..\endcsname`, thus: Additionally to egreg's comment: For example a control-sequence defined in terms of `\toksdef` is neither a primitive nor expandable but leads to an error-message inside `\csname..\endcsname` unless preceded by `\the`. Errors are also thrown in case of characters of category code 15 occurring in the .tex-input. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

A fairly general loop:

```latex
documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\loopvar}{m +O{} m +O{}}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 } { #2 \use:c { #1##1 } #4 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\cta}{\texttt{\string\cta}}
\newcommand{\ctb}{\texttt{\string\ctb}}
\newcommand{\ctc}{\texttt{\string\ctc}}
\newcommand{\ctd}{\texttt{\string\ctd}}

\begin{document}

\loopvar{ct}{a,b,c,d}

\loopvar{ct}[This is ]{a,b,c}[\par]

\end{document}
```

The first mandatory argument is the common part, the second mandatory argument is the list of strings to append; the first optional argument is a “prefix” to add before the macro, the traling one is the “postfix”.

Explanation: `\use:c` builds a control sequence name from its argument and is essentially `\csname...\endcsname` in disguise; `\clist_map_inline:nn` maps the comma separated list executing for each item the code specified in the second argument (`#1` stands for the current item, but here we need to use `##1` because we're defining a macro).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As in TeX everything is about tokens that might be expandable, you are faced with the question about the order in time in which expansion of `\cta`, `\ctb`, `\ctc`, `\ctd` shall take place.

Case 1:

Is the loop to deliver the entire token-sequence `\cta\ctb\ctc\ctd` ?

(In case `\cta` is a macro that processes three non-delimited arguments, its first argument is the token `\ctb`, its second argument is the token `\ctc` and its third argument is the token `\ctd`.)

Case 2:

Is the token `\cta` to be produced and expanded totally and carried out completely in the first iteration, then the token `\ctb` to be produced and  expanded totally and carried out completely in the second iteration, then the token `\ctc` to be produced and expanded totally and carried out completely in the third iteration, then the token `\ctd` to be produced and expanded totally and carried out completely in the fourth iteration?

How to do the second case has already been shown by [campa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/555671/118714)  and [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/555674/118714).

So let's focus on the first case:

You could use a scratch-macro for accumulating tokens:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\cta}[3]{%
  \noindent
  \texttt{\string\cta}'s first argument is: \texttt{\string#1}\\%
  \texttt{\string\cta}'s second argument is: \texttt{\string#2}\\%
  \texttt{\string\cta}'s third argument is: \texttt{\string#3}%
  
  \bigskip

  #1#2#3%
}
\newcommand*{\ctb}[2]{%
  \noindent
  \texttt{\string\ctb}'s first argument is: \texttt{\string#1}\\%
  \texttt{\string\ctb}'s second argument is: \texttt{\string#2}%

  \bigskip

  #1#2%
}
\newcommand*{\ctc}[1]{%
  \noindent
  \texttt{\string\ctc}'s first argument is: \texttt{\string#1}%

  \bigskip

  #1%
}
\newcommand*{\ctd}{%
  \noindent
  \texttt{\string\ctd} does not process arguments.%
}

\newcommand\scratchmacro{}%

\begin{document}

\def\scratchmacro{}
\foreach \i in {a,b,c,d}{%
  \csname g@addto@macro%
           \expandafter\endcsname
           \expandafter{%
           \expandafter\scratchmacro
           \expandafter}%
           \expandafter{%
             \csname ct\i\endcsname
          }%
}%

\noindent
\texttt{\string\scratchmacro: \meaning\scratchmacro}

\bigskip

\scratchmacro

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wish a fully expandable loop, then you are faced with the task of expandable comma-list-parsing.

In this case you might be interested in the answers to the question [`\newcommand` with many arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498354/118714).

If you wish a fully expandable loop, but can make it with a list of non-delimited arguments instead of a comma-list, i.e., something like `{a}{b}{c}{d}` instead of `a,b,c,d`, then you are faced with the task of expandable argument-list-parsing.

In this case you might be interested in some of the answers to the question [defining a new command with variable name in a loop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/539742/118714).

---

Another approach could be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\UD@exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\nameloop{\romannumeral0\UD@innernameloop}%
\newcommand\UD@innernameloop[3]{%
  \ifx\relax#3\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  { #2}{%
    \expandafter\UD@exchange
    \expandafter{%
    \expandafter{%
      \romannumeral0%
      \expandafter\UD@exchange\expandafter{%
        \csname#1#3\endcsname
      }{ #2}%
    }}{%
      \UD@innernameloop{#1}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\scratchmacro
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \nameloop{ct}{Tokens in front}{a}{b}{c}{d}{\relax}%
}%

\begin{document}

\texttt{\string\scratchmacro: \meaning\scratchmacro}

\end{document}
```

[image]